# Backup sharepoint site to a .bak file

Tags: sharepoint-2010, backup

I have a sharepoint Farm with different web applications and I'd like to back up two of the web applications.

Using Sharepoint 2010 Central Administration Panel -> Backup and Restore, I see I can select the web application, and choose full or differential backup, then create the backup.

This method creates a folder with lots of small files. On the machine I can see that the historical backups are single very large .BAK files. I am concerned I'm not doing this correctly.

How do I create a similar file -a single .BAK file? Is that perhaps a database backup instead of a web application backup? I'm going to have some work done on the web application and would like to able restore the web app to it's current state in case something goes wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.  When you run a full backup in SharePoint it creates all of those little .BAK files so that you can selectively restore components.  Look in the backup directory and find a file called `spbackup.xml`, this is a full breakdown of every item that was backed up and the associated .BAK file.  Your SQL databases are included in here as well, just look for your content database name in that xml file and you will see the details of the backup.  It should look something like this:

```
<SPBackupObject Name="WSS_Content">
    <SPBackupRestoreClass>Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</SPBackupRestoreClass>
    <SPBackupSelectable>True</SPBackupSelectable>
    <SPRestoreSelectable>True</SPRestoreSelectable>
    <SPName>WSS_Content</SPName>
    <SPId>f1f517f9-00b0-4863-96c0-fb57ae1ac579</SPId>
    <SPCanBackup>True</SPCanBackup>
    <SPCanRestore>True</SPCanRestore>
    <SPCurrentProgress>100</SPCurrentProgress>
    <SPLastUpdate>03/19/2013 10:01:08</SPLastUpdate>
    <SPCurrentPhase>Done</SPCurrentPhase>
    <SPParameters>
        <SPParameter Key="f1f517f9-00b0-4863-96c0-fb57ae1ac438STATE.xml"><![CDATA[00000016.bak]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="InstanceId"><![CDATA[12ef83f5-8e21-4696-afb5-8210f2baadfb]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="ServerId"><![CDATA[735385ba-f55a-4a8b-bc5c-3ef7ff7221c1]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPDescription"><![CDATA[Content for the Web Application.]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPDiskSize"><![CDATA[140181504]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPLocation"><![CDATA[C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SHAREPOINT\MSSQL\DATA]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPName"><![CDATA[WSS_Content_EOTA]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPServer"><![CDATA[SQL\SHAREPOINT]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPSqlFullLocation"><![CDATA[\\backupsrv\Backup\SharePoint\spbr0055\0000010A.bak]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPSqlPreviousPosition"><![CDATA[1]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SPTimeout"><![CDATA[3600]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="SQL\SHAREPOINT:WSS_Content.dat"><![CDATA[000000F9.bak]]></SPParameter>
        <SPParameter Key="Url"><![CDATA[http://dev.sharepoint.local/]]></SPParameter>
    </SPParameters>
</SPBackupObject>
```